# How do I avoid printing space between two parameters to print?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have

```
>>>i=65536
>>>print('The value of i is', i)
The value of i is 65536
```

How do I get the output (notice the lack of space between `is` & `65536`)

```
The value of i is65536
```

Without manipulating the strings prior to the `print()`

Comment: When you have a question like this, it's usually worth either typing `help(print)` into the interactive interpreter, or searching [the online docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print). (Or, if you use an IDE that has built-in help, search that instead.) Most answers—including this one—have an easy answer that you'll spot immediately.

Comment: I am going with the python.org tutorial. Have not seen it there, maybe it comes later. Will remember the help(print) though, they did not mention that

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka: I didn't realize it doesn't mention the `help` command early on. That really ought to be covered right when they introduce the interactive interpreter in chapter 2. You want to file a docs bug on that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two choices.

First, you can use the `sep` keyword argument to the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function:

```
print('The value of i is', i, sep='')
```

Or, better, you can use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead of a multi-argument `print` call:

```
print('The value of i is{}'.format(i))
```

The second one is a lot more flexible, and more readable for any but the simplest cases. But either one works.

Comment: Although not pertinent to this Python 3.x tagged question, FWIW, another advantage of the `format()` string method approach is that it would work in Python 2.6+. Similarly, `print('The value of i is' + format(i))` which uses the built-in `format()` function also works in both versions.

Comment: @martineau: Good point, which may be helpful to future searchers coming off the `[python]` tag rather than `[python-3.x]` (or just to someone who needs to write a single codebase that's 2.6+/3.2+, which is still a pretty common target). Except that with 2.6, you'd need `{0}` instead of `{}`; you need 2.7 or… I think 3.2?… to leave out the indices.

Answer (score 2):

```
print('The value of i is', i, sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

`print('The value of i is{my_var}'.format(my_var=i))`

or

`print('The value of i is' + str(i))`

Comment: You can't add strings to integers in Python.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `str`.  Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do it is:

`i=65536
print('The value of i is', end='')
print(i)`

When you do:

```
end=''
```

You are making it so it does not skip to the next like after finish that print statement.